# Pass only one variable to a function in Python

Tags: python, function

Let's say I have the function

```
def f(x,y):
    return x+y
```

and I want to create a function that returns a function in which a specific variable is passed:

```
def G(f,n,q):  #a function in which the n-th variable of function f is passed the value q
    return ??
```

The question is: how should I define `G`?

For example, `G(f,0,1)` should return the function `f` in which variable 0 is passed the value one. In other words, `G(f,0,1)` should behave as `g`, which I define by

```
def g(x):
    return f(1,x)
```

Comment: What should be returned for `G(f,1,2)`, a function with `def g(x): return f(x,2)`?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: I think he means the variable with *index* 0.

Comment: Indeed Willem, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case you can construct a function that construct a function. Like:

```
def G(f,n,q):
    def h(*args):
        ls = list(args)
        ls.insert(n,q)
        return f(*ls)
    return h
```

You thus construct a function `h` that takes as input an arbitrary number of elements `*args`. Then you convert it to a `list(..)` such that you can alter the list. Next you insert the given parameter `q` as index `n` into the list, and you pass that list with an asterisk to the given function `f`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a smaller, simpler, related working example. In general, you might want to read about python decorators and partial functions.

```
>>> def power(x):
...     def foo(y):
...         return y**x
...     return foo
...
>>> square = power(2)
>>> cube = power(3)
>>> square(2)
4
>>> square(3)
9
>>> cube(2)
8
>>> cube(3)
27
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [`functools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html) module.

For example, using the `partial` method you can do:

```
from functools import partial
def G(f, n, q):
  return partial(f, n=q)
```

This replaces the keyword argument named `n` with`q`

You could also replace positional arguments but they have to be in order:

```
from functools import partial
def G(f, n, q):
  return partial(f, q)
```

This replaces the first argument with `q`

Comment: This does not work if `n` is not `0`: `G(f,1,1)` does not work correctly (if you write `f(x,y): return (x,y)`...